# Compiler can't find the method to add KeyListener to my classes

Tags: java, keylistener

I am very new to Java.

This is some code from a text book and I have an error on the `addKeyListener(this)` line and the `text.addKeyListener(this)` line:

> The method addkeyListener(JUpsideDown) is undefined for the type JUpsideDown.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JUpsideDown extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Flipping text");
    private JLabel lblNewLabel1 = new JLabel();
    private JTextField text = new JTextField(20);

    public JUpsideDown() {

        setTitle("Flipping text");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(lblNewLabel);
        add(text);
        add(lblNewLabel1);
        addkeyListener(this);
        text.addkeyListener(this);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        lblNewLabel1.setText("Last Key: " + c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUpsideDown test = new JUpsideDown();
        test.setSize(500,500);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `addkeyListener` to `addKeyListener` (with capital K). In your introduction you wrote it correctly, but in the code it was misspelled. Since method names are case-sensitive, the compiler did not find the method `addkeyListener` in the components trying to invoke it, and gave the appropriate compilation error.

Comment: HA! Thank you! I was up late writing this and knew it had to be something silly. I just could not see it! Thank you!